# How can I disable symmetry in sculpting mode?

Tags: sculpting

I know this has probably been asked before, but I'm watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lj643VmTsg) where the guy's sculpting and telling you to disable Symmetry X under the sculpt menu.

The video: [image]

Mine: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to enable the properties window. In the tool tab you will find the symmetry options.

Or they can also be found in the properties tool panel on the right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be sure to tick your comment after the system allows me

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised by the other answer. No need to go to the N-panel, scroll etc. it's right here on top all the time. Just check or uncheck the axis to toggle symmetrize.
[image: screenshot]